# JS Datepicker: Disable past dates + specific days of the week + specific dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker in JS where I disabled passed dates AND only allow saturdays like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#aankomstdatum").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        numberOfMonths:2,
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [day == 6];
    }});
});
```

I also have a code that lets me disable specific dates like this:

```
 /** Days to be disabled as an array */
var disableddates = ["26-05-2018"];

function DisableSpecificDates(date) {

 var m = date.getMonth();
 var d = date.getDate();
 var y = date.getFullYear();

 // First convert the date in to the mm-dd-yyyy format 
 // Take note that we will increment the month count by 1 
 var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y ;

  // We will now check if the date belongs to disableddates array 
 for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {

 // Now check if the current date is in disabled dates array. 
 if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {
 return [false];
 }
 }
}
```

With adding this, it works:

```
beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
```

The issue I have is that i can't make both work. I'm not sure How can disable the past dates and all days except saturdays AND also disable specific given dates in the array, while seperatly they do work. I always get syntax errors when trying for example:

```
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates, function(date){
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [day == 6];
}});
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to achieve this. You want to create one function and return `[false]` from it if:

1. `date` is a Saturday or
2. `date` is contained within `disableddates` array

Here's the example:

```
var disableddates = ["26-04-2018"];

function DisableDates(date) {
  var selectable = !isSaturday(date) && !isDateDisabled(date);

  return [selectable];
}

function isSaturday(date) {
  var day = date.getDay();

  return day === 6;
}

function isDateDisabled(date) {
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = date.getDate();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  // First convert the date in to the dd-mm-yyyy format
  if(d < 10) d = '0' + d;
  if(m < 10) m = '0' + m;

  var currentdate = d + '-' + m + '-' + y;

  // Check if disableddates array contains the currentdate
  return disableddates.indexOf(currentdate) >= 0;
}
```

And then just pass `DisableDates` function as the value of your `beforeShowDay` option:

```
$("#aankomstdatum").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
  numberOfMonths:2,
  minDate: 0,
  beforeShowDay: DisableDates
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I see the logic in your code, but i can't make it seem to work. Here's a JS Fiddle I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/qrnaszqz/ Thank your all your help!

Comment: @KevinVerhoeven You have to add external resources (your datepicker plugin). Now it fails because $(...).datepicker is undefined.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I adjusted accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/qrnaszqz/1 As soon as I uncomment "beforeShowDay: DisableDates" The calender doesn't work anymore. When commented, it does work. So there might be a bug somewhere?

Comment: @KevinVerhoeven I've updated the answer, example code should work now. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7y28td3r.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Thanks for persisting to find the solution.